# Can you make an immutable struct in C# w/UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, immutability

So best practice is to make immutable structs in C#.

```
public struct Foo
{
    readonly private int bar;
    public Foo(int i)
    {
        bar = i;
    }
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
    }
}
```

In UWP, this doesn't work, one gets a:

```
error WME1013: 'Blah.Foo' contains non-public field 'System.Int32 Blah.Foo.bar'.  Windows Runtime structures can contain only public fields.
error WME1012: Type 'Blah.Foo' contains non-field member 'Blah.Foo.Bar.get()'. Windows Runtime structures can contain only fields.
error WME1012: Type 'Blah.Foo' contains non-field member 'Blah.Foo..ctor(System.Int32)'. Windows Runtime structures can contain only fields.
error WME1012: Type 'Blah.Foo' contains non-field member 'Blah.Foo.Bar'. Windows Runtime structures can contain only fields.
```

So, ok, I get that, public UWP structs are really really a value type, so let's go to basics...

```
public struct Foo
{
    readonly public int Bar;
}
```

And now.... let's initialize... with an object initializer?

```
class FooTest
{
    public static void FooFunc()
    {
        var baz = new Foo { Bar = 2 };
    }
}
```

But nope

```
error CS0191: A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer
```

Is there any way to do this, or should I do one of:

1. Accept mutable structs
2. Use a class

Comment: UWP cannot provide an abstraction for a struct, they work the way they do in a C program.  Yes, either approach is fine.

Comment: The way you've phrased your question is misleading: neither C# nor UWP impose that kind of restrictions on structs. It probably makes sense to emphasize that you work with _public_ structs within a _Windows Runtime Component_ project or something like that.